# Discrete closed subsets in Lindelöf spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Lindelöf space and let $A$ be a discrete closed subset of $X$. Then $A$ must be countable. Indeed, for any $x \in A$, the singleton $\{x\}$ is an open subset of $A$. Obviously, the sets of all such singletons is an open covering of $A$; since $A$ is a Lindelöf space (because it is a closed subset of a Lindelöf space), we may cover $A$ with countably many singletons. This shows that $A$ is a countable set.

Do you agree that this is a valid argument? An exercise in Bourbaki's Topology asks to prove the above under the hypotheses that $X$ is an accessible (i.e. $T_1$) Lindelöf space. I can't see where the $T_1$ hypothesis is useful.

Thank you.

Comment: It's valid. I don't see where $T_1$ would be useful either. Perhaps it's useful in some part of the context, if it's part of a group of exercises and some other exercises in that group require $X$ to be $T_1$.